# Why does CopyOnWriteArrayList.get need no synchronization?

Tags: java, locking, volatile, java.util.concurrent

just had a look at class CopyOnWriteArrayList and I wondered why its get(...) method doesn't need any synchronization. The add(...) and set(...) methods change the underlying array in a mutex block using ReentrantLock. But get(...) just returns the raw underlying array without any synchronisation. Okay, the underlying array is declared volatile:

```
private volatile transient Object[] array;
```

But I don't see how using volatile makes any synchronisation redundant. It only prevents the reference stored in array from being cached by the compiler. If I understood why synchronisation is not needed here I could write my code with a little less lock contention than before ...

Thanks, Oliver

Comment: The name of the class is a hint.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can CopyOnWriteArrayList be thread-safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950871/how-can-copyonwritearraylist-be-thread-safe)

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel: You were right. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I think the accepted answer in that thread misses an important point. The other answer is more accurate.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950871/how-can-copyonwritearraylist-be-thread-safe as pointed out by Mark Rotteveel

Comment: The real answer is that volatile since JDK1.5 is also atomic, see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp03304/

Comment: @OliverPlow not sure what you mean - volatile guarantees atomic `double` and `long` assignment but that's it. Other assignements are always atomic, regardless of volatility.

Comment: @OliverPlow you are getting atomicity and visibility confused. `volatile` guarantees visibility. Reference assignments are always atomic.

Answer (score 1):

The clue is in the name (as MarkRotteveel pointed out).

When any change is made the change is made in a separate `Object[]` then the whole lot is copied over - "copy on write".

As the internal `Object[]` is `volatile` when the reference is changed from the old `Object[]` to the new `Object[]` the change is picked up by all threads.

Answer (score 1):

It uses a little "trick" - when the underlying array is changed, the sequence of events is:

1. create a new array
2. populate the new array
3. change the reference held by the class to point to the new array

The third step writes to `private volatile transient Object[] array;` - due to volatile semantics, all changes made before step three are made visible.

So not only is the new reference visible, but **the content of the new array is also made visible** (that's the trick).